# Use custom powershell module in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I wrote function PowerShell module like that:

```
    Function docConvert2{
         param ([string]$sourceFile, [string]$sourceFilePath)
         ....
         ....
    }
```

I've imported module successfuly

[image]

And i can use module in powershell cmdlet

[image]

When i try call function in c#, i got exception like that

> The term 'docConvert2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

C# code

```
        PowerShell pShell = PowerShell.Create();
        pShell.Commands.AddCommand("import-module").AddParameter("Name", "DocConverter2");
        pShell.Invoke();//works correctly
        pShell.AddCommand("docConvert2");
        pShell.AddParameter("sourceFile", "'addendum no-3_PREP.doc'");
        pShell.AddParameter("sourceFilePath", @"'D:\New\wordler'");
        pShell.Invoke();//throw exception
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
PowerShell pShell = PowerShell.Create();
pShell.Commands.AddCommand("import-module").AddParameter("Name","DocConverter2");
pShell.Invoke();
...
rest of you code here
...
```

You can also use InitialSessionState to preload module: [read here](http://nivot.org/blog/post/2010/05/03/PowerShell20DeveloperEssentials1InitializingARunspaceWithAModule)

Comment: Thank you for advice but Unfortunately, this do not work. I got same exception, i wrote comment about that in Eoin's answer.

Comment: I try but Unfortunately this do not work again. However i found some borderline case. If I run powershell.exe from Run, Powershell.exe run in "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>" path and If I run PowerShell.exe in Start, PowerShell.exe run in "C:\Users\Dreamcatcher>" path. Is it cause of problem?

Comment: @Dreamcatcher It's the normal behaviour. Copy& paste my code and try change "DocConverter2" in the AddParameter with the full path of your psm1 module file

Comment: Haha i missed it :) Thank you it works. But why i have to load module every time? Is it true way?

Comment: @Dreamcatcher In powershell V1 and V2 is the only way (or load modules in the profile ). In V3 powershell dinamically look up cmdlet or function in all available modules.

Answer (score 0):

After instantiating your `pShell` object, you need to import your module, same as you did from the command line.

Try executing the following between lines 1 & 2.

```
        ps.AddScript(@"import-module DocConverter2");
        ps.Invoke();
```

And make sure your C# application has access to the path that your PSM is located in.

Comment: I think this is not necessary because i imported module before but i try your advices and don't work i got same exception. I've updated my code after your advices in question.